# react native with moment.js

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I use native react to develop a mobile application.
I retrieve some information of an API on which I loop of which a date in this format:

```
 "2018-06-02T10: 00: 00 2018-06-02T11: 00: 00; 2018-06-03T10: 00: 00 2018-06-03T11: 00: 00"
```

I know it's the ISO 8601 format, I'd like to make it look better, so I try to use Moment.js but I can not.

Here is the part of my code (of course I did not forget to import Moment.js):

Here is my code (of course I did not forget to import Moment.js):

```
                    <View style={styles.contentItem}>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>{Moment(item.fields.timetable).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}</Text>
                  <Foundation name="clock" style={styles.icons} />
                </View>
```

I find myself with an error "invalid date", do I do wrong? Can you help me or give me some leads, please ?

Comment: Can you check that `2018-06-02T10: 00: 00 2018-06-02T11: 00: 00` is this correct one?

Comment: Send single date which you get it from server.

Comment: please check api retrive time fomrat ?

Comment: Thank you, I tried the solution proposed by Ali sn and it works: D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a single date to `moment` not an array of dates. You can pass input date formatting to `moment` like this:

```
let date = "2018-06-02T10: 00: 00"
let correctDate = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH: mm: ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
```

Answer (score 0):

As your getting date as **String**, so you need to convert it into **Date** then you can update formate as you want. Below is the answer:

```
  const stillUtc = moment.utc(YOUR_DATE).toDate();
  const local = moment(stillUtc).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm your format is not exactly `ISO 8601`. You have some extra space.

Can you replace for example `2018-06-02T10: 00: 00` by `2018-06-02T10:00:00`. ? (If date is with timezone you can add a `Z` at the end `2018-06-02T10:00:00Z`

Be sure also to give just one `Date` to `Moment` and not an `array`.

Hope this helps !